# I am creating a program to read MNIST Datasets. I am getting this error. How to overcome this error

Tags: python, tensorflow

My code to convert numeric data into gray scale and after that convert it into 28*28 size.But from this code I could not get my image in output and get error if I an try to remove reshape line from code it shows image but that image does not give proper shape.

```
 from PIL import Image
    user_test = filename
    col = Image.open(user_test)
    gray = col.convert('L')
    bw = gray.point(lambda x: 0 if x<100 else 255, '1')
    bw.save("bw_image.jpg")
    bw
    img_array = cv2.imread("bw_image.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    img_array = cv2.bitwise_not(img_array)
    print(img_array.size)
    plt.imshow(img_array, cmap = plt.cm.binary)
    plt.show()
    img_size = 28
    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (img_size,img_size))
    plt.imshow(new_array, cmap = plt.cm.binary)
    plt.show()
    user_test = user_test.reshape(-1,img_size,img_size)
    user_test = tf.keras.utils.normalize(new_array, axis = 1)
    predicted = model.predict([[user_test]])
    a = predicted[0][0]
    for i in range(0,10):
      b = predicted[0][i]
      print("Probability Distribution for",i,b)
    
    print("The Predicted Value is",np.argmax(predicted[0]))
```

Error Get:

```
 AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-34-04ae8dbf024e> in <module>()
         15 plt.imshow(new_array, cmap = plt.cm.binary)
         16 plt.show()
    ---> 17 user_test = user_test.reshape(-1,img_size,img_size)
         18 user_test = tf.keras.utils.normalize(new_array, axis = 1)
         19 predicted = model.predict([[user_test]])
    
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'reshape'
```

Comment: what are you trying to do here:`user_test = user_test.reshape(-1,img_size,img_size)`
for now you try to reshape the path of the first image, it's normal that it doesn't work

Comment: how could I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying reshape 'user_test' which is just a string containing path to file as in line 2, `user_test = filename`.
So, obviously you can't rehape it.
Instead you can & you should the array obtained after opening that image file. For example, `img_array` or `new_array` can be reshaped.